# Clarifying a proof of homotopy lifting in John Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading John Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*, Second Edition. I have some doubts about the proof of Theorem 8.4 (homotopy lifting property of the circle) on page 221, specifically in the second paragraph of the proof.

Let's say we have a standard covering $\varepsilon:\Bbb R\to S^1$, $\varepsilon(t)=e^{2\pi it}$, a locally connected space $B$, two continuous functions $\varphi_0,\varphi_1:B\to S^1$, a homotopy $H:B\times[0,1]\to S^1$ from $\varphi_0$ to $\varphi_1$, and a lift $\tilde\varphi_0:B\to \Bbb R$ of $\varphi_0$. The aim is to construct a lift $\tilde H:B\times[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ of $H$.

The argument in the book for existence of lift $\tilde H$ starts as follows.

> Pick any point $b_0\in B$. For each $s\in[0,1]$, pick an evenly covered neighbourhood $U$ of $H(b_0,s)\in S^1$. $H^{-1}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $(b_0,s)$ and this open set is, by definition of product topology, a union of some $V\times J$ where $V$ is an open set in $B$ and $J$ is an open set in $[0,1]$. Of course there are some such $V\times J$ containing the point $(b_0,s)$. The collection all such $V\times J$ with the property that $(b_0,s)\in V\times J$ is an open cover of $\{b_0\}\times[0,1]$.

This is where I find a bit problematic. We are not sure if $\{b_0\}\times[0,1]\subseteq H^{-1}(U)$. I think what the author means is that we allow $s\in[0,1]$ to vary from $0$ to $1$ to get a larger collection of $V\times J$. Then the larger collection of all such $V\times J$ covers each of the points $(b_0,s)$ where $b_0$ is kept fixed and $s$ varies, i.e. the larger collection covers $\{b_0\}\times[0,1]$.

After the above interpretation, I have to reinterpret the following arguments in the book.

> We then pick finitely many open sets from the larger collection, say $V_1\times J_1,...,V_m\times J_m$. A set $W\in V_1\cap...\cap V_n$ is chosen and a length $1/n$ is chosen so that each of $[(j-1)/n,j/n]$ is a subset of one of $J_i$. Then $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$ is a subset of some $V_i\times J_i$, and so each of $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$, $j=1,...,n$, is mapped by $H$ into an evenly covered open set in $S^1$.

I think there may not necessarily be a single evenly covered open set $U$ which all of $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$ is mapped by $H$ into $U$. I think what the author means is that this evenly covered open set depends on $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$, that for each $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$, there is an evenly covered open set $U_j$ in $S^1$ which satisfies $H(W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n])\subseteq U_j$.

Is my interpretation of the proof correct?

Comment: I've only ever seen this proven by invoking the Lebesgue covering lemma.  That would seem to fix this issue.

Comment: @Randall Of course I know the author used Lebesgue number lemma. The choice of $1/n$ in the second quote is precisely taken to be smaller than a Lebesgue number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure of the argument could be clearer.  Let me put it into outline form:

- Let $b_0\in B$ be arbitrary.
- For all $s\in[0,1]$:

  - Let $U$ be an evenly covered neighborhood of $H(b_0,s)\in S^1$.
  - Since $U$ is a neighborhood in the product topology $B\times [0,1]$, there is an open $V_s\subset B$ and open $J_s\subset [0,1]$ such that $(b_0,s)\in V_s\times J_s\subset U$.
- The collection $\{V_s\times J_s\}_{s\in [0,1]}$ is an open cover of $\{b_0\}\times [0,1]$.

Your question stems from a justifiable confusion about the *binding* of $U$.  This variable is only defined for a particular $s$, and it is not defined once $s$ is no longer in the scope of the "for all."  In the outline form of the proof, the scope of $s$ extends through the sublist.  In the last line, the $s$ that shows up is a variable distinct from the $s$ introduced in the second line.

Continuing the outline (which is something like the tube lemma, by the way):

- Since $\{b_0\}\times[0,1]$ is compact, there is an finite subcover $V_{s_1}\times J_{s_1},\dots,V_{s_m}\times J_{s_m}$ indexed by some $s_1,\dots,s_m\in[0,1]$.
- Let $W=\bigcap_{i}V_{s_i}$, so we may assume the finite cover of $\{b_0\}\times[0,1]$ is $W\times J_{s_1},\dots,W\times J_{s_m}$.
- Let $1/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be less than the Lebesgue number of the cover $J_{s_1},\dots,J_{s_m}$ of $[0,1]$.
- Then, for all $j=1,2,\dots,n$:

  - There exist some $i$ such that $W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n]$ is contained in $V_{s_i}\times J_{s_i}$.
  - Hence $H(W\times[(j-1)/n,j/n])$ is a subset of some evenly covered subset (that depends on $j$; if I had changed $U$ to $U_s$ in the first outline, then I could give the name $U_{s_i}$ to this subset).

You are correct that in general there is not a single evenly covered subset containing the image.  I leave it to you to think of a counterexample.